# How to retrieve the HBITMAP from a Picture Control (MFC c++)?

Tags: c++, mfc, hbitmap

I would like to know how to get the HBITMAP from a Picture Control (MFC c++). 
I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap1 = 
    (HBITMAP)SendMessage(GetDlgItem(m_hWnd,IDC_VIEW),STM_GETIMAGE,
    (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM) 0);
HBITMAP hBitmap2 = (HBITMAP)CopyImage (hBitmap1, 
                    IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG);
```

Thank you

Comment: _'but it didn't work:'_ is pretty vague.

Comment: it didn't work: hBitmap1 and hBitmap2 are always NULL.

Comment: So I'd suspect something was going wrong with `SendMessage()` in first place.

Answer (score 0):

Call GetBitmap on the CStatic control.

Comment: the picture control has as a style SS_BLACKFRAME. the function GetBitmap() dosn't work.  <i>CStatic * cscontrol = (CStatic*)GetDlgItem(m_hWnd,IDC_VIEW);
 HBITMAP hBitmap2= cscontrol->GetBitmap();</i>

Comment: So how did the control get a bitmap? If you are painting it yourself it does not have a bitmap. Also: The version of GetDlgItem you are calling returns an HWND, not a CStatic*.